# Extending django User Model (Unable to add extra fields)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am new to django, I am trying to extend Django User Model with few extra parameters. I tried the following solution and tried different workarounds too but didnt't get successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code files.

**admin -> init__.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from usermanagement.models import UserProfile 

scrumboard_models = [models.Board, models.Setting, models.CheckList, models.CheckListItem,
                     models.Comments, models.Subscribers, models.Lists,
                     models.Label, models.Card, models.Attachment, models.Team]

admin.site.register(scrumboard_models)

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'id', 'first_name', 'username', 'email', 'is_active', 'dob'
    )

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

**Settings.py**
"""
Django settings for app project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/

"""
import os

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

import datetime

JWT_AUTH = {
  'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
}

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'v!t5abxm^t@tyj=z5gp!*_%qy=$q-d6g!4zx(!r3_nn)7h^ee7'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'scrumboard',
    'admin_app',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'corsheaders',
    'usermanagement',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}

# Database

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "NAME": os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'scrumboard'),
        "USER": os.environ.get('USER', 'postgres'),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get('PASSWORD', '112233'),
        "HOST": os.environ.get('HOST', 'localhost'),
        "PORT": os.environ.get('DB_PORT', 5432),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '1234567890'

EMAIL_USE_SSL=False

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# ======================================================================================================================
# CORS SETTINGS
# ======================================================================================================================

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usermanagement.UserProfile'
```

**usermanagement.models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

from django.utils import timezone

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Create your models here.

class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('dob') is not True:

            dob = None

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:

            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email, username=username,
                          first_name=first_name, password=password, **other_fields)

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    about = models.TextField(_(
        'about'), max_length=500, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:

        abstract = False

    def __str__(self):

        return self.username

[Project Structure][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Wkp.png
```

Parameters **dob , gender** are added into database but are not showing up in django admin portal.

Comment: Can you post the error

Comment: There is no error. But fields extended fields are not showing up in django admin portal while creating new user

Answer (score 0):

when I did this kind of thing I had to do the following:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Separately I also had this code in my `admin.py` file:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

My `Profile` model  is just a normal model I.E. `class Profile(models.Model):...`
Specifically:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
   otherfield = ...
   dob = ...
   gender = ...
   phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=17, null=True, blank=True)
 ....

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

I think the base `User` model may be still in place and you need to unregister it to put in your custom `UserProfileAdmin`